# Inheritance of super constructor methods

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor, prototype

Let me explain what I think going on:

1. We create constructor User and add info() to it's prototype
2. We create UserAdmin constructor and by calling `User.call(this, name);` we call User constructor to inherit
3. When we call `Object.create(User.prototype, {constructor:{...}});` we inherit all methods from User prototype and add constructor to be consistent.
4. I can't understand why `someFunc` and all other functions are added to UserAdmin's prototype...Is there any way not to inherit functions, which are added to superclass prototype?

```
function User(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
User.prototype.info = function () {
  return this.name;
};

function UserAdmin(name, privileges) {
  User.call(this, name);
  this.privileges = privileges;
}
UserAdmin.prototype = Object.create(User.prototype, {
  constructor: {
    value: UserAdmin,
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
  },
});
// let meAdmin = new UserAdmin("meAdmin", "edit");
// meAdmin.someFunc()  // meAdmin.someFunc is not a function 
User.prototype.someFunc = function() {
    console.log("I am created in User prototype")
}
let meAdmin = new UserAdmin("meAdmin", "edit");
meAdmin.someFunc()  // I am created in User prototype
```

Comment: I can't understand why someFunc and all other functions are added to UserAdmin's prototype and I want to know if there any way not to inherit functions, which are added to superclass prototype?

Comment: Because you're setting `UserAdmin.prototype = Object.create(User.prototype, ...)`. `User.prototype` is a reference, all the references to it refer to the exactly same object. It's ofcourse good to know about how things work in JS, but there are [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) for much more convenient inheriting.

Comment: @Teemu Classes seems to be so convinient way to work, I just wanted to feel like a programmer 15 years ago))) I checked with ```UserAdmin.prototype !== Object.create(User.prototype, ...)``` , but I was mislead by reference, thank you

Comment: _"2. We create `UserAdmin` constructor and by calling `User.call(this, name);` we call User constructor to inherit"_. Nope ... by invoking `User.call(this, name);` one does augment the to be created `UserAdmin` instance with a `User` type's `name` property. At this point it is composition and resembles thee `UserAdmin` constructor's `super` call when practicing real, class based, sub-classing in JavaScript.